# Line intersection in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry

Is it enough to say that if two lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have a different gradient, they intersect at most once?

I have two general vector equations of lines and I'm struggling to show they only intersect once directly from the formulas but I'm thinking maybe a more geometric argument will be appropriate in this case. Any suggestions would be amazing!

Comment: I *assume* you are specifically referring to this occurring within Euclidean Geometry?  If you have never even heard of non-euclidean geometry then the answer is yes, but this needs to be confirmed.

Comment: @JMoravitz The OP is talking about $\mathbb{R}^3$, what am I missing here?

Comment: In any case, @Bcpicao the OP's claim is that all pairs of lines will either intersect infinitely often, exactly once, or exactly no times and that the lines being of different gradient implies that it is one of these second two cases.  In euclidean geometry, that is indeed true.  To see this, suppose otherwise that you have two lines who both intersect in at least two places.  You can show then that they intersect along the entire infinite line segment between those points and they have the same gradient.

Comment: @JMoravitz I missed the **at most**... Thanks! Just out of curiosity, what type of non-euclidean geometry are you thinking about? Do all of them lack that property? I can see why it works for spherical, but not for hyperbolic or projective geometry.